# how can i evaluate my spark application

Tags: performance, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing

hello i just finished creating my first spark application, now i have access to a cluster (12 nodes where each node has 2 processors Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 2.00GHz, where each processor has 8 cores), i want to know what are criteria that help me to tuning my application and to observe its performance.

i have already visited the official website of spark, it's talking about Data Serialization, but i couldn't get what is it exactly or how to specify it.

it is talking also about "memory management", "Level of Parallelism" but i didn't understand how to control these.

one more thing, i know that the size of data has an effect, but all files.csv that i have have small size, how can i get files with large size (10 GB, 20 GB, 30 GB, 50 GB, 100 GB, 300 GB, 500 GB)

please try to explain well for me, because cluster computing is fresh for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tuning you application you need to know few things

1) You Need to Monitor your application whether your cluster is under utilized or not how much resources are used by your application which you have created

Monitoring can be done using various tools eg. Ganglia
From Ganglia you can find **CPU, Memory and Network Usage**.

2) Based on Observation about CPU and Memory Usage you can get a better idea what kind of tuning is needed for your application

Form Spark point of you

In spark-defaults.conf

you can specify what kind of serialization is needed how much Driver Memory and Executor Memory needed by your application even you can change Garbage collection algorithm.

Below are few Example you can tune this parameter based on your requirements

```
spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory              5g
spark.executor.memory            3g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -XX:+UseG1GC
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -XX:MaxPermSize=6G -XX:+UseG1GC
```

For More details refer http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

**Hope this Helps!!**

Comment: why do we use spark.serializer , for wich reason?

Comment: how can i  modify spark-defaults.conf using the shell (because i can access to nodes only via the shell)

Comment: spark-defaults.conf file is present in spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\conf directory you can modify as per your requirement.

Comment: Serialization plays an important role in the performance of any distributed application. Formats that are slow to serialize objects into, or consume a large number of bytes, will greatly slow down the computation. Often, this will be the first thing you should tune to optimize a Spark application. Spark aims to strike a balance between convenience (allowing you to work with any Java type in your operations) and performance. It provides two serialization libraries: Java serialization and Kryo serialization

Comment: you didn't get me well,i can only use the shell to access to my cluster (nodes) so how can i specify my needs through commands?

Comment: and thank you very much, you really helped me to understand the serialization concept :)

Comment: if i understood you question this is what you are looking for ./spark-submit --master  'spark://macXXX:7077' --driver-memory 1G --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 2G --class com.abc.main /home/spark/main.jar  yes we can submit all the require parameters from command line... If you like my answer vote for my answer :)

Comment: does it exist a flag to control the level of parallelism ? (command)

Comment: are you looking for this spark.default.parallelism,12

Comment: ./spark-submit --conf "spark.default.parallelism=12" at run time :)

Comment: For distributed shuffle operations like reduceByKey and join, the largest number of partitions in a parent RDD. For operations like parallelize with no parent RDDs, it depends on the cluster manager:
Local mode: number of cores on the local machine
Mesos fine grained mode: 8
Others: total number of cores on all executor nodes or 2, whichever is larger

Comment: Default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like join, reduceByKey, and parallelize when not set by user.

Comment: if i set the level of parallelism, do i have to set the number of executers per node too?

Comment: not necessary as per my knowledge i might be wrong..... i am still learning spark

Comment: if i don't set the level of parallelism and set the number of cores of executers, will it be the same?

Comment: i want to add this to spark-submit ; spark.eventLog.enabled  true,   which flag do i have to use ?? --conf?